# Create List of 100 Random Integers, Return Max Value

Tags: python, list, function, random, integer

Write a Python function that will take a the list of 100 random integers between 0 and 1000 and return the maximum value. (Note: there is a builtin function named max but pretend you cannot use it.)

Here's what I tried:

```
import random

list = []
for i in range(100):
    list.append(random.randint(0,1000))          

def max(list):
    #sort list from least to greatest
    answer = list.sort()
    #get last item in list (max value)
    list.pop()

    return max  

print (max(list))
```

As you can see, what I'm confused about is how to correctly use the sort and pop methods to return the max value within the max function. I'm currently getting:

```
ParseError: bad input on line 12
```

Which is this line:

```
list.pop()
```

Not sure how to correct this. Thanks.

Comment: There's actually a builtin [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function in python. You could just do this: `print(max(list))` -- you don't need to define a `max()` function.

Comment: Please don't call your list `list` (it's the name of built-in type; while Python wouldn't prevent you from using the name for something else, this has the potential for causing lots of confusion).

Comment: @csinchok we can't use the max() function for this assignment.

Comment: If your instructor appreciates alternative answers: `def max(l): return -min(-i for i in l)` or `def max(l): return min(l, key=lambda i:-i)`

Comment: @Robᵩ this is so evil-genius-like. Hahaha nice! How about `def max(l): return min(l, key=lambda i:1/i`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You have to be careful about that method because in python 2, integer division is always used as long as both operands are integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_list.sort()` sorts the list itself. If you want to store your sorted list in `answer`, you should use:

```
answer = sorted(my_list)
```

You can also use a list comprehension to generate your first list as follows:

```
>>> random
>>> 
>>> my_list = [random.randint(0, 1000) for i in range(100)]
>>> answer = sorted(my_list)
>>> answer.pop()
996  # This should be different each time
```

Now, your function can be:

```
def max(my_list):
    # sort list from least to greatest
    answer = sorted(my_list)
    # get last item in list (max value)
    max = answer.pop()

    return max
```

If you still want to use the same list, you can do:

```
my_list.sort()
max = my_list.pop()
```

**Note that:** I prefer to call the list `my_list` because `list` is a python keyword.

Comment: So then to store the sorted list, and to store the last item of that sorted list in answer, I would do answer = sorted(list)
                                              pop(list)  ? Trying that still gave me the parse error.

Comment: How weird is it that when i ran my code i got `996` too? Can this be a coincidence?

Comment: Yeah this is what I was going for. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @ettanany I wasn't suggesting that the output is the same every time. I just found the coincidence interesting but if you actually do the math it is not that unlikely at all.

Answer (score 3):

1) Your indentation was off

2) You managed to overwrite 2 Python builtins in 4 lines of code (`max()` and `list()`))

3) `my_list.sort()` does not return a list. It operates in place sorting the list in-place. On the contrary, `sorted(my_list)` does return a list so you can either do `my_list.sort()` or `my_list = sorted(my_list)`.

4) Your `return` was just wrong.

See the code below:

```
a_list = []
for i in range(100):
    a_list.append(random.randint(0, 1000))

def my_max(my_list):
    return sorted(my_list)[-1]  # here, the list we passed gets sorted and its last item is retrieved (item with index -1)

print(my_max(a_list))
```

Other interesting answers (hats off to @Rob) that feature a bit of cockiness:

```
def my_max(my_list):
    return min(l, key:lambda i: 1/i)
```

or

```
def my_max(my_list):
    return min(l, key:lambda i: -i)
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually try to avoid using names that are have a predefined function / built-in names, this helps to avoid problems quite often. Like this it should work.

```
import random

my_list = []
for i in range(100):
    my_list.append(random.randint(0,1000))          

def my_max(my_list):
    #sort list from least to greatest
    my_list.sort()
    #get last item in list (max value)
    my_max = my_list.pop()

    return my_max

print my_max(my_list)
```